# "Laptop Notebook Memory for Apple Mac Mini"? Does this sound right?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, mac-mini

I am shopping for memory for a MacBook Pro (mid-2009) and I found [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00607HG9A). Supposedly, it is "Laptop Notebook Memory for Apple Mac Mini". Can such memory be used in a Mac Mini? Can it be used in the MBP I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite this answer from a reviewer on the product that you mentioned:

> My 2011 Macbook Pro came with 4GB of memory. I usually run several
>   (~10) apps simultaneously and need more memory. Even with fewer apps,
>   I noticed that Safari's Web Process always increases in size and
>   eventually leaves no free memory available. I looked at the choices
>   for 2x4GB of PC3-10600 and Komputerbay's price was enticing. I
>   installed them over two weeks ago and have not had a problem.

I would **not** trust buying this for a MBP. For a Mac Mini, that may be fine. But, it is always a good idea to stick with memory designed for your specific Apple computer.

Why don't you get [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00607HE0G)? It is from the same seller (Kcomputerbay) and it is around the same price. It also is for the MBP.